# handling a special character in a string while storing to a record on sqlite

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, wxwidgets

in the following piece of code, I see that when my 'description' is something like:
`"     '    '     "`, I have a problem updating the description to the sqlite record.
How do i handle the ' character. thanks!

```
sql = wxString::Format(
"UPDATE event SET event_description='%s' WHERE id=%d",
description.c_str(),
event_id);
rc = sqlite3_exec((sqlite3 *)_theDB, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &sqlError);
```

The OP answered his own question:

> check this out [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14) we need to replace the occurences of ' with '' in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubling up all the single quotes in the description string is one way to do it.  This way you can avoid malicious descriptions (see [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

```
 ' '
```

becomes:

```
 '' ''
```

And more importantly, the potentially dangerous description:

```
' WHERE 1=1 DELETE FROM Event --
```

becomes the harmless:

```
'' WHERE 1=1 DELETE FROM Event --
```

Another (safer) way, is to use [prepared statements](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html).